# How to get total for top n rows (not for whole dataset) in SSRS 2017

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2017

I need to get SUM for TOP 10 rows only by counting unique claim numbers. Not for the whole dataset.

for that in a group properties I set Filter with expression:

[image]

But the total sum reflected for the whole dataset, not for top 10.

I tried using `RunningValue` finction, but no success:

https://mkncreations.com/site/2012/05/filter-top-n-group-totals/

[image]

What would be the way to capture sum for only top 10 rows?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create row inside the group
   2.Enter expression referencing dataset name (not group name):

   =RunningValue(Fields!IdemnityReserves.Value,SUM,"UnitedSpecialty")
2. Make this row invisible
3. Add total row
4. Enter expression in total row referencing cell created in step 2:

   =reportitems!Textbox288.Value